# Selenium Firefox profile preferences download dialogue box

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automatically log into several websites and download reports.

In my profile preferences, I have set the following:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", folder1)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/plain,text/x-csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/csv,application/x-csv,text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,application/pdf,text/html")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,text/x-csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/csv,application/x-csv,text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,application/pdf,text/html")
```

For all the websites, except for 1, the files download without the dialog box showing.

However, one of them always shows the dialog box.

I am thinking it is due to the filename being called "Download.CSV", with the csv file extension in capitals...but I'm not convinced.

All the other files that successfully downloaded from the other websites were in csv file with a lower case csv file extension. This is the only difference I can think of.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will come across this issue, I solved it.

Although the file extension was "CSV", the MIME type from the server was listed as "application/octet-stream".

Adding this to my Firefox profile preferences fixed the issue.